# Is there a way to have a child div's background expand outside of parent div?

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

```html
<div id = 1>
   <div id = 2>
     //I want to expand the background of this div outside of the bounds 
     //of is parent
   </div>
</div>
```

So I have a div nested inside of another div. The parent div is aligned to the center of the screen. I want the child to be able to have a background that takes up the width of the screen without changing the position of the content inside. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative margin to accomplish that:

```
margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
```

Checkout a quick JSFiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcsra5yg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::after` to achieve this.

html

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, in.</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  background:rgba(255,255,255, .6);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}

.child:after {
  z-index:-1;
  content:'';
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/rbBzgq)

[EXAMPLE 2](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/PgYOwB)

Comment: I don't want to set the entire page background to a color (or an image in some cases). I just want to have background to the div take up the width of the screen.

Comment: You've sed " I want the child to be able to have a background that takes up the width of the screen". The screen for me means the whole viewport. Do you want your child div to be as big as it's parent? if so how much outside of the parent you want that background?

Comment: Check EXAMPLE 2, hope I helped :)